# strategies for avoid mysql queries in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

i have an app (rails 3) that basically is a social network for tv shows. So users can interact with each others and with tv_shows.

What would be the best strategy to avoid quering the database (mysql) every time when showing users/tv_shows profiles pages?

Ex: Inside a tv show profile page, i need to load a lot of information like seasons, episodes, actors etc. To do this a need to join several tables and is getting slower each day.

My first thought was gether all information regarding any tv show and storage in just one table, so i dont need to make those joins every time.

For sure i would have better performance but not best. I know that there are a lot of alternatives out there like memcache, redis even mongodb but what is the best approach to this case?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet, in my opinion, is to cache a marshalled object for each `Show` that contains the pre-fetched data for all the relations that are required to render the page. I use Redis as my cache but you can also use Memcache or something simmilar.

```
shows = user.tv_shows.map do |show|
  if cached_show = $redis.get("shows:#{show.id}")
    # use the cached object
    Marshal.load(cached_show)
  else
    # cache has expired or was never created
    show.prefetch!
    # set the cache for the next visit and have it expire after +TIMEOUT+
    $redis.setnx("shows:#{show.id}", TIMEOUT, Marshal.dump(show))
    show
  end
end
```

It is important to prefetch all of your relations before you dump the object, otherwise you will hit the database after you unmarshall the cached object.

Here is an example of prefetching:

```
class Show
  def prefetch!
    @actors ||= actors
    self
  end

  def actors
    @actors || 1.upto(10).map do |n|
      Actor.new(n)
    end
  end
end

class Actor
  def initialize(n)
    puts "initialize actor #{n}"
  end
end

show = Show.new.prefetch!
cache = Marshal.dump(show)
Marshal.load(cache).actors.length  # uses value stored in @actors

show2 = Show.new
cache2 = Marshal.dump(show2)
Marshal.load(cache2).actors.length  # calls database
```

Comment: thanks, i give it a try but what about space? we more then 30k shows and almost 1M shows episodes. I dont have a clue how much space im gonna need for this. It could be a little expensive for a beta project.

Comment: In Redis it is possible to set a `maxmemory` configuration value. When `maxmemory` is reached Redis uses the eviction policy you specify. In this case you would want to specify `allkeys-lru` which will remove keys that were 'least recently used'. This way the 'hot' shows will be kept in redis while others will be removed when `maxmemory` is hit. `setex` will also delete the key after `TIMEOUT` number of seconds. https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#l258-304